# Failure Build failed with an exception after updated Android Gradle Plugin to 4.1.0

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle, android-r8

I am getting Build Failure Exception after I updated AGP to 4.1.0 and gradle wrapper to 6.5-all

compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion is 30

> ./gradlew --stacktrace assemble

is throwing following error if I am setting **minifyEnabled = true** , it is Building successfully if I set it false.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':project-name:minifyReleaseWithR8'.

> Cannot query the value of this property because it has no value available.

- Complete Stacktrace

> ```
> Exception is:
>     org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.TaskDependencyResolveException: Could not determine the dependencies of task ':project-name:minifyReleaseWithR8'.
>             at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.getDependencies(CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.java:69)
>             at org.gradle.execution.plan.TaskDependencyResolver.resolveDependenciesFor(TaskDependencyResolver.java:46)
>             at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNode.getDependencies(LocalTaskNode.java:161)
>             at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNode.resolveDependencies(LocalTaskNode.java:129)
>             at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultExecutionPlan.doAddNodes(DefaultExecutionPlan.java:165)
>             at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultExecutionPlan.addEntryTasks(DefaultExecutionPlan.java:135)
>             at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.addEntryTasks(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:144)
>             at org.gradle.execution.TaskNameResolvingBuildConfigurationAction.configure(TaskNameResolvingBuildConfigurationAction.java:49)
>             at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:58)
>             at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:26)
>             at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:66)
>             at org.gradle.execution.DefaultTasksBuildExecutionAction.configure(DefaultTasksBuildExecutionAction.java:45)
>             at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:58)
>             at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:26)
>             at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:66)
>             at org.gradle.execution.ExcludedTaskFilteringBuildConfigurationAction.configure(ExcludedTaskFilteringBuildConfigurationAction.java:48)
>             at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:58)
>             at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:26)
>             at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter$1.run(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:44)
>             at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:26)
>             at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry.withLenientState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:134)
>             at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry.withLenientState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:126)
>             at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.select(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:40)
>             at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultTaskExecutionPreparer.prepareForTaskExecution(DefaultTaskExecutionPreparer.java:38)
>             at org.gradle.initialization.BuildOperatingFiringTaskExecutionPreparer$CalculateTaskGraph.populateTaskGraph(BuildOperatingFiringTaskExecutionPreparer.java:117)
>             at org.gradle.initialization.BuildOperatingFiringTaskExecutionPreparer$CalculateTaskGraph.run(BuildOperatingFiringTaskExecutionPreparer.java:68)
>             at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:395)
>             at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:387)
>             at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:157)
>             at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:242)
>             at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:150)
>             at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:84)
>             at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
>             at org.gradle.initialization.BuildOperatingFiringTaskExecutionPreparer.prepareForTaskExecution(BuildOperatingFiringTaskExecutionPreparer.java:56)
>             at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.prepareTaskExecution(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:227)
>             at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doClassicBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:159)
>             at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:140)
>             at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.executeTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:120)
>             at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.create(GradleBuildController.java:74)
>             at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.create(GradleBuildController.java:67)
>             at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:180)
>             at org.gradle.internal.work.StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.java:40)
>             at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:67)
>             at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:56)
>             at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:31)
>             at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
>             at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.java:63)
>             at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
>             at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.java:39)
>             at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:51)
>             at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:45)
>             at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:409)
>             at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:399)
>             at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:157)
>             at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:242)
>             at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:150)
>             at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:94)
>             at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
>             at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:45)
>             at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$1.transform(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:50)
>             at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$1.transform(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:47)
>             at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.run(DefaultRootBuildState.java:80)
>             at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:47)
>             at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:31)
>             at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:42)
>             at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
>             at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:87)
>             at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:55)
>             at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.java:60)
>             at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.java:38)
>             at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:68)
>             at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:38)
>             at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:37)
>             at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
>             at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:60)
>             at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:32)
>             at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:56)
>             at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:42)
>             at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:48)
>             at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:32)
>             at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:68)
>             at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
>             at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
>             at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:39)
>             at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
>             at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:29)
>             at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
>             at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:35)
>             at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
>             at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:78)
>             at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
>             at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
>             at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
>             at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
>             at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
>             at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
>             at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:63)
>             at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
>             at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
>             at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:82)
>             at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
>             at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
>             at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:52)
>             at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
>             at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
>             at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
>             at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
>     Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.provider.MissingValueException: Cannot query the value of this property because it has no value available.
>             at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractMinimalProvider.get(AbstractMinimalProvider.java:86)
>             at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.UnpackingVisitor.add(UnpackingVisitor.java:56)
>             at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultConfigurableFileCollection$UnresolvedItemsCollector.visitContents(DefaultConfigurableFileCollection.java:300)
>             at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultConfigurableFileCollection.visitContents(DefaultConfigurableFileCollection.java:224)
>             at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection.visitDependencies(CompositeFileCollection.java:140)
>             at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultConfigurableFileCollection.visitDependencies(DefaultConfigurableFileCollection.java:230)
>             at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext$TaskGraphImpl.getNodeValues(CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.java:112)
>             at org.gradle.internal.graph.CachingDirectedGraphWalker$GraphWithEmptyEdges.getNodeValues(CachingDirectedGraphWalker.java:213)
>             at org.gradle.internal.graph.CachingDirectedGraphWalker.doSearch(CachingDirectedGraphWalker.java:121)
>             at org.gradle.internal.graph.CachingDirectedGraphWalker.findValues(CachingDirectedGraphWalker.java:73)
>             at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.getDependencies(CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.java:67)
>             ... 106 more
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is related to Android Gradle plugin 4.1, here is the thread of google issue tracker. Also attaching their reply.
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/171364505

> When running R8 on library projects we should avoid passing
> DEX-specific options like main dex list or core library desugaring as
> these are applicable only when building DEX.
>
> As a temporary workaround, you can remove multiDexEnabled true from
> the library build script.
>
> This is now fixed in master and AGP 4.2-beta01 should contain the fix.
> We are yet to evaluate if the fix will be cherry-picked to 4.1 branch.

Change: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/8166c944221cc273cd63fb08a4f1dc6bf18e6725